Codeception: Rightclicking on webelement and then selecting the first option is not working
I am using codeception as the IDE to write my automation tests using php.
Problem statement:
I want to right click on a web element > From the list of menu items visible post the right click, I want to select/highlight/move the control to the first option: 'Open link in new tab'

Issue faced
Through automation, I am able to right click on the web element and can see the list of options > But I am not able to move the control to click on the 1st option of opening link on the new tab.
My code:
<?php

namespace Page\UI;

use AcceptanceTester;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;

class RoughRighClickPracticePage {

    /**
     * @var \UITester;
     */
    protected $tester;
    public static $admin;

    // we inject AcceptanceTester into our class
    public function __construct(AcceptanceTester $I) {
        $this->tester = $I;
    }

    public $webElement = 'x-path of web element';


    #With clickWithRightButton() the following function is doing the right click properly but not sure what to do next to move the control to the menu option next
    
    public function roughRighClick1(): void {
        $I = $this->tester;
        $element = $this->webElement;
        $I->clickWithRightButton($element);
    }
    
#Thus I tried the following with the pressKey() function to right click & open the link in new tab in one go: but nothing happened

    public function roughRighClick2(): void {
        $I = $this->tester;
        $element = $this->webElement;
        $I->pressKey($element, \Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverKeys::BUTTON_MIDDLE); #Manually clicking the middle button of mouse does the trick
}
}

